# How to count every single space as a character?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Working with CK-Editor and I allow users to paste characters in it. I'm not counting HTML tags as a character (I'm just ignoring HTML tags), and if user enters a space I'm counting it as a **single** character. Finally, I'm  **only** allowing users to enter up to 50 characters.

**My issues:**

**1)** If user pastes 50 characters (including spaces) CK-editor should count every single space as it was a character.

**2)** If user enters **more** than 50 characters show an alert message saying ("You cannot enter more than 50 characters"), and display only 50 characters. 
I tried doing:
`event.data.dataValue = str.substr(0 , textLimit);` but it always gets rid of spaces and puts `multiple spaces` as if it was a `single space`.

**3)** If user pastes 9 characters 6 times. Example: user pastes 9 characters, then another 9, then another 9, then another 9, then another 9, then another 9. Once going over 50 characters, the user should get an alert message ("You cannot enter more than 50 characters"), but still, show 50 characters. Is there a better way to prevent users from pasting more than 50 characters?. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:
Live Demo: [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/hon9t7L1/3/)

```
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('paste',function(event){
 var textLimit = 50;
 var str = event.data.dataValue.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');

 if (str.length >= textLimit) {
 event.data.dataValue = str.substr(0 , textLimit);
 } 
});
```

**NOTE:**
- I'm using this site to count the characters - https://www.lettercount.com/

- Here's an image to show how I'm counting the spaces:

[image]

Comment: It seem we can't resolve the first problem. Because html element will convert > 2 space to just one space.

Answer (score -1):

Try wordcount plugin. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount
And on config.js in your ckeditor folder, use this to configure wordcount.

```js
config.wordcount = {

        // Whether or not you want to show the Paragraphs Count
        showParagraphs: false,

        // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
        showWordCount: false,

        // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
        showCharCount: true,

        // Whether or not you want to count Spaces as Chars
        countSpacesAsChars: true,

        // Whether or not to include Html chars in the Char Count
        countHTML: false,

        // Maximum allowed Word Count, -1 is default for unlimited
        maxWordCount: -1,

        // Maximum allowed Char Count, -1 is default for unlimited
        maxCharCount: 100,

        // Add filter to add or remove element before counting (see CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter), Default value : null (no filter)
        filter: new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter({
            elements: {
                div: function (element) {
                    if (element.attributes.class == 'mediaembed') {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: @Haetanto I don't want to use an external plug in